# Show and Hide span on click

Tags: jquery

I am using this code to reveal a phone number on my website

```
<span id="ares">Click to show</span><span id="areshow">+44 111 111177</span>

jQuery("#ares").click(function() {jQuery("#areshow").fadeToggle();jQuery("#ares").fadeToggle();});
```

It works however, the problem is that until `#ares` is hidden, `#areshow` is misplaced for a few milliseconds.

Comment: you can see both elements at the same time during the transition for a split second... ideally 'ares' must be hidden instantly I believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should likely call the `fadeToggle` for the `#areshow` element during the `complete` event for the `#ares` call.  That would look like this:

```
jQuery("#ares").click(function() {
    jQuery("#ares").fadeToggle(400, 'swing', function () {
        jQuery("#areshow").fadeToggle() 
    });
});
```

Comment: this works but why use 'swing' ? can i use something that fades in more smoothly ?

Comment: you can, but according to the docs, swing is the default: http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/.  I don't think standard jQuery has any besides `swing` and `linear`, others are in the jQueryUI